# CS50 filter - pointers between functions

Tags: c, pointers, filter, cs50

first time using stackoverflow so if my post comes out weird that's why. For those familiar with the cs50 filter project I need some assistance with the blur function. I have already completed the project so I know without the check_pixel function this works, but I want to tidy it up a bit. I know that I need to assign my averages to address of image[x][y], but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

The error message I get from the compiler is: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid).

```
void check_pixel(int height, int width, int x, int y, RGBTRIPLE *store, 
RGBTRIPLE *image)
{
    float sumRed = 0;
    float sumGreen = 0;
    float sumBlue = 0;

    //printf("%p\n", &image->rgbtRed);


    int pixel_count = 0;

    for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = y - 1; j < y + 2; j++)
        {
            if (i < 0 || i >= height || j < 0 || j >= width)
            {
                ;
            }
            else
            {
                sumRed += store->rgbtRed;
                sumGreen += store->rgbtGreen;
                sumBlue += store->rgbtBlue;
                pixel_count++;
            }
        }
    }

    *image->rgbtRed = round(sumRed / pixel_count);
    *image->rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / pixel_count);
    *image->rgbtBlue = round(sumBlue / pixel_count);

    return;
}


// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    RGBTRIPLE store[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            store[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    //iterate through the height of the image
    for (int x = 0; x < height; x++)
    {
        //iterate through the width of the image
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
        {
           
            check_pixel(height, width, x, y, &store[x][y], &image[x][y]);

        
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't dereference here `*image->rgbtRed = ....`, just do `image->rgbtRed = ...; image->rgbtGreen = ... ; image->rgbtBlue = ... `

Comment: Aesthetically pleasing code! Nice! The `< x + 2` is jarring, however. You use `>=` below that. Why not use `for (int i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++)`?? Especially like the 'positive logic' of the `if( )`... Readable! Well done...

Comment: `check_pixel` computes `i` and `j` very carefully and then never uses them to actually index any array, do you think it's OK?

Comment: _Side note:_ You can move the `i` related `if` expressions to the outer loop (e.g.): `for (int i = x - 1; i < x + 2; i++) { if ((i < 0) || (i >= height)) continue; for (int j = y - 1; j < y + 2; j++)` since they are _invariant_ within the `j` loop. A good compiler optimizer will probably do this but it is [IMO] cleaner if you do it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
*image->rgbtRed = round(sumRed / pixel_count);
*image->rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / pixel_count);
*image->rgbtBlue = round(sumBlue / pixel_count);
```

To

```
image->rgbtRed = round(sumRed / pixel_count); 
image->rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / pixel_count);
image->rgbtBlue = round(sumBlue / pixel_count);
```

Doing `*image->x` is equivalent to `*(*image).x` which incorrect.

Since `image` is a pointer to a `struct`, there is no need to include the extra `*` at the start. Using `->` will suffice when referencing members of the `struct`.

Comment: I realised that my issue is somewhere else. Thanks for the help, your confirmation let me know my problem was elsewhere.